# My node editor is broken

Tags: node-editor

When i try to add a material to new files , and use nodes to customize it opens up some 2 nodes i know nothing about , and whenever i try to add anything it lacks half of the functions it had before. My old files are still ok , and have all the things i need to customize nodes.[image]

Comment: maybe you've switched from Cycles Render to Blender Render?

Comment: Oh , yeah xd
  Thanks , i'm kinda new to blender

Comment: Internet is spotty here, this was the quickest I could find. Also duplicates of duplicates quickly provide the user with a breadcrumb trail of potentially useful posts, they can effortlessly go through, as opposed to presenting a single answer. It hopefully also encourages them to search more often

Answer (score 2):

Switch from Blender Render to Cycles Render, on the top horizontal menu bar.

[image]