# When I go to the Node Editor to look at my object's material I can't find any nodes

Tags: materials, objects, node-editor

Whenever I open up Blender the material of the cube is already added and when I go to node editor I can't find any nodes. How can I make it so that my objects don't automatically get a material when I open Blender and I can see the nodes?

Comment: [Possibly Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115892/my-node-editor-is-broken)

Comment: Do you remember to switch to the cycles renderer? Also if material is created in Blender Internal, you will have to click on "use nodes" in the bottom of the node editor with the object selected

Answer (score 1):

The cube you find when you start Blender has a default material called "Material". Check the "use nodes" checkbox to see them.
[image]